# Error al eliminar elementos de un arreglo mientras se recorre

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un arreglo y quiero eliminar, por ejemplo, los múltiplos de 3. Lo recorro pero no se porque me da error, y no me lo elimina.

```
def eliminar(a):
    l = len(a)
    for i in range(0, l):
        if a[i]%3==0:
            a.remove(a[i])
```

Desde el cuerpo llamo a la función:

```
a=[]
...
#lo cargo
...
eliminar(a)
...
```

Recibo el error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: La próxima deja el error que recibes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No conviene modificar la coleccion sobre la que iteras.

Generalmente, tratar de borrar elementos de una coleccion mientras se recorre, trae un problema:

Lo curioso, es lo que hace este código:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for item in lista:
    if(item == 3):
        lista.remove(item)

print(lista)
```

Que produce

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Como podrás ver, la iteración no siguió correctamente eliminando los 3 de la lista.

###### Suposición

El iterador relacionado con la lista, el cual probablemente lleva un contador interno, no se actualiza cuando la lista pierde o adquiere un item. Eso significa que la iteración funciona así

```
posición 0 -> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> item 1
posición 1 -> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> item 2
posición 2 -> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> item 3 (remueve el 3)
posición 3 -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> item 4 (se salta el 3 por que el contador no se actualizó)
...
```

Al parecer, los diccionarios SI avisan que su tamaño cambió produciendo un error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

###### ¿Podríamos cambiar esto?

Podríamos crear nuestro propio iterador que tenga un contador y que este contador se actualize automaticamente según se eliminen o agregen items de la lista. Pero hace trabajar de más al programador y a la maquina, que tiene que hacer estos chequeos.

###### Por que no usar .remove para eliminar multiples elementos.

Ten en cuenta que, al usarse remove, Python se pone a buscar elemento por elemento hasta encontrar uno que coincida. Si podemos obtener la posición directamente (con un contador o con matematica) eliminar según indice es más rapido.

Ten en cuenta esto para listas grandes.

#### La mejor solución

Lo habitual, es que se recurra a crear un nuevo iterador, iterable o collecion e ir agregando o devolviendo los elementos que no queríamos remover. Esto le da menos trabajo al programador y a la maquina.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 3]
nueva_lista = []

for item in lista:
   if(item != 3):
       nueva_lista.append(item)
```

O, usando [comprensión de listas](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/):

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 3]
nueva_lista = [item for item in lista if item != 3]
```

Comment: @ Dante S. Gracias, funciona mejor. Pero no ocupa el doble de espacio hacer una lista auxiliar? Hay alguna forma que funcione sin hacer dicha lista?

Comment: Python tiene variables por referencia: las variables, las listas, etc, no guardan una copia del valor que reciben, si no una id que hace referencia al objeto o numero en memoria. Por lo que el espacio extra ocupado es insignificante. Sin embargo, si la lista que buscas crear es en realidad una lista auxiliar que luego vas a recorrer, podrías usar una comprensión de generador (lee el link al final de la respuesta, esa pagina lo explica muy bien) o una función generadora .

Comment: Te doy un ejemplo: si querés obtener todos los multiplos de 3 almacenados en un rango, te conviene más (a menos de que tu objetivo final sea una lista) usar comprensión de generador. Ya que los generadores van "generando" valores y no se mantienen en memoria los valores anteriores, a diferencia de las listas. Ten en cuenta que el objeto range calcula los numeros conforme son necesarios.

Comment: @Severus puedes hacer una pregunta nueva sobre eso y ver qué respuestas obtienes.

Answer (score 3):

Se está generando un rango fijo para un arreglo que va a cambiar durante la iteración. Por eso ocurre el error.

Para ser más claro, el rango se crea antes del ciclo y sirve para iterar el arreglo por sus posiciones.

Cuando borras un elemento, el tamaño del arreglo disminuye pero el rango sigue siendo el mismo.

Por lo tanto, llegará un momento en que se intente acceder a una posición inválida.

---

Los arreglos pueden ser iterados directamente mediante el `for`. Es decir, la variable de iteración toma el valor de cada uno de sus elementos.

Por ejemplo:

```
arreglo = [ 1, 5, 8 ]
for elemento in arreglo:
    print(elemento)
```

Produce la salida:

> 1
>
> 5
>
> 8

La ventaja de esta forma es que no da errores si se borran elementos mientras tanto.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
def eliminar(arreglo):
   for numero in arreglo:
      if numero % 3 == 0:
         arreglo.remove(numero)
```

Como mencionó Dante, este método no funciona cuando hay elementos consecutivos que eliminar.

---

Una segunda forma de hacerlo es por posiciones. Para eso se necesita una variable `i` que aumente solo si el elemento actual no es eliminado.

Este es el código:

```
def eliminar(arreglo):
   i = 0
   while i < len(arreglo):
      if arreglo[i] % 3 == 0:
         arreglo.pop(i)
      else:
         i += 1
```

Por cierto, también se puede usar `remove`. Es mejor `pop` porque es más fácil borrar el elemento de una posición y conocemos esa posición. `remove` tiene que buscarlos en el arreglo antes de poder eliminarlos.

Comment: @ Mateo porque elimino numero según tu código? Me funciono, pero no entendí porque. numero no es la posición (la cantidad de repeticiones que realizo) en el que esta el ciclo for?

Comment: @Severus dime si ahora lo entiendes. Con `range`, la variable de iteración adquiere los valores 0, 1, 2, 3 y así que puedes usar para acceder a los elementos de un arreglo por sus posiciones. Si usas el arreglo directamente en el for (a la derecha del `in`), la variable de iteración toma cada elemento del arreglo.

Comment: Tu respuesta no funciona bien cuando hay dos numeros iguales seguidos. Prueba con una lista de estilo [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. Te devuelve [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]. Lee 
[mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/580619/158880)